# PHP Array Index arithmetic and Aggregation

Tags: php, math, aggregation

I have 3 arrays with a list of documents that have been read in from three search engines. The array contains crucial information such as url, title, and description.

Ultimately I wish to rank the documents in the array and aggregate them using [Reciprocal Rank Fusion](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/cormacksigir09-rrf.pdf) whereby the document is scored based on its rank in each array:

```
Document_Score = (1/(60+rank_google)) + (1/(60+rank_yahoo)) + (1/(60+rank_bing))
```

**The problem is:**

I need to isolate each document by checking its url which uniquely identifies the document. 
So the crucial information is contained in the following:

```
googlearray[$i]['url'];
yahooarray[$i]['url'];
bingarray[$i]['url'];
```

**Question:**

Can anybody suggest a simple way  in which I can isolate a particular document (based on its **url**) in each engine so that I have perform the aggregation formula on each document? *(efficiency is nice but simple will do for now)*

Any clues or suggestions at all are welcome :)

Thanks.

Comment: your `$bingscore[$i]` is another array. you should do a print_r($bingscore[$i]) and see the output before overwriting the data.